# The set of all points where $(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is differentiable, $n$ odd

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know this might be a silly question.

Recently I encountered this question, where I was asked to find the set of all points $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the function $f(x,y):=(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is odd, is differentiable at $(x,y)$.

I immediately came up with $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,y)\ | \ y=-x\}$, since the partial derivatives don't even exist on the line $y=-x$.

However, I wasn't able to prove that everywhere else on the plane, the function is differentiable.

Here's some of the steps that I came up with:

> $\nabla f (x,y) =(x^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1},\ y^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1})$ 
>
> If $y \neq -x$, 
> $$lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{((x+h)^n+(y+k)^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}-(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}-hx^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}-ky^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$
> $$=lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\{[(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}][\frac{((x+h)^n+(y+k)^n)-(x^n+y^n)-n(hx^{n-1}+ky^{n-1})}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}]-\frac{((x+h)^n+(y+k)^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}-(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}((x+h)^n+(y+k)^n)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\}$$
> $$=-lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}[(x+h)^n+(y+k)^n][\frac{((x+h)^n+(y+k)^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}-(x^n+y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}]$$
> since the term in first term converges to zero by differentiability of $x^n+y^n$.

From here on, I was unable to evaluate the limit, but I believe it also converges to zero.

Am I on the right track or is there a much easier way?